# How to merge a huge number of small files into one file

Tags: c#, archive

I have a about 1.5 million small files, with a total size of about 80 GB.

I want to merge these files into one file to be fast to copy. I tried to archive them into a zip file and read the the files with this code:

```
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(Settings.Default.DataPath); 
ZipEntry entery = zip[MyFile];
```

The idea worked, but it too slow, it took about 30 seconds to load one file.

Is there any another faster idea to merge the files?

Thanks

Comment: Probably, you need SSD :)

Comment: There's the principle of conversation of energy. At some point you cannot optimize stuff any more. You *may* be able to use better hardware, or refactor your data base of small files into something more manageable (have you considered distributing the files onto several locations and use indexed access to retrieve them?)

Comment: what do you want , merge file or make an archive of severals files ?wich type of file ? you want copy then access ?

Comment: Use a SQLite database, a zip file with 1.5 million files will be slow to index into since the table of files in the archive will be read sequentially. Create a database instead with an index on the filename. It will likely be slightly bigger than 80GB, but you could also try to compress each individual file before storing into the database.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : It's good idea, Thanks a lot,  I will insert the files in to SQLite file, please set this comment as an answer to approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use [SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) (you can add it through a Nuget package) and create a database file that holds all these individual bits of data.

You would create a table that holds all the files and make the filename the primary key, which would automatically create an index on it:

```
CREATE TABLE files
(
    filename TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    content BLOB
)
```

You would then insert all the files into it, one row per file.

To retrieve it, you would execute SQL like this:

```
SELECT content FROM files WHERE filename = ?
```

I would encapsulate all of this into a new class so that you separate out the functionality of maintaining and using this file from the rest of your application.